# How to get filtered activity stream using Yammer API?

Tags: yammer

Yammer Activity Stream is available at:

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/streams/activities.json?access_token=
```

This successfully results in all the recent activities like:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "id": "/users/www.yammer.com-341514-1508953644/rollups/45191477209921-45191477209921",
        "unseen": true,
        "icon": "/images/notifications/page_add.png",
        "icon_name": null,
        "category": "file-create",
        "message": "[[user:1508783078]] uploaded [[uploaded_file:24511980]].",
        "heading": "",
        "created_at": "2014/10/02 07:07:42 +0000",
        "objects": [],
        "actions": [],
        "subject": {
            "type": "uploaded_file",
            "id": 24511980
        },
        "meta": null,
        "client_type": "unknown",
        "client_url": "https://www.yammer.com",
        "client_icon": "https://mug0.assets-yammer.com/mugshot/images/16x16/3rd_party.png",
        "client_large_icon": "https://mug0.assets-yammer.com/mugshot/images/75x75/3rd_party.png",
        "image": "https://mug0.assets-yammer.com/mugshot/images/48x48/no_photo.png",
        "third_party": false
    },
    {
        "id": "/users/www.yammer.com-341514-1508953644/rollups/45191475863746-45191475863746",
        "unseen": true,
        "icon": "/images/notifications/page_add.png",
        "icon_name": "page",
        "category": "file-download",
        "message": "[[user:1508783078]] downloaded [[uploaded_file:24373320]] from the [[group:3455089]] group.",
        "heading": "",
        "created_at": "2014/10/02 07:07:00 +0000",
        "objects": [
            {
                "id": 24373320,
                "type": "uploaded_file"
            }
        ],
        "actions": [],
        "subject": {
            "type": "uploaded_file",
            "id": 24373320
        },
        "meta": null,
        "client_type": "unknown",
        "client_url": "https://www.yammer.com",
        "client_icon": "https://mug0.assets-yammer.com/mugshot/images/16x16/3rd_party.png",
        "client_large_icon": "https://mug0.assets-yammer.com/mugshot/images/75x75/3rd_party.png",
        "image": "https://mug0.assets-yammer.com/mugshot/images/48x48/no_photo.png",
        "third_party": false
    },
]}
```

**QUESTION:**
I am trying to get all the recent activities after a certain time-stamp or after a certain offset. Is there any query parameter for that?

Comment: This is an unsupported API which is subject to change at any time without notice. It's risky to build a solution on top of it.

Comment: We thought we could use this API in our application to give users an ability to glance at what happened recently. We use a concept of workspaces (groups) where people work on the same project. A user can be a member of several workspaces. When someone does something in a workspace, we could post to `activity.json` endpoint and then somewhere in our application get the recent activities from `streams/activities.json` and dispaly it to the user. Is this a good idea? Are there any alternatives using Yammer API? How about the V2? We also want to customize the recent activities's UI.

Answer (score 0):

this is

```
older_than="/users/www.yammer.com-341514-1508953644/rollups/45191475863746-45191475863746"
```

that would return all the activities older than the last activities you shew in your sample return value